# How to get the name and suffix of the picture in the rich text field?

Tags: apex, rest-api, tooling-api

[image]

String strName = 'yes-circle-ma…';

String Image_Type = 'PNG';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The actual image will be saved to a [rtaImage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_rich_text_image_retrieve.htm), and the file name will be lost as a result. You can still determine the type by checking the headers for the image when you retrieve the URL (Content-Type), but that's it.